# Wiring RGB Strip LEDs w/ just positive and negative wire

Tags: led, led-strip, basic

I'm working on a small project, and I had some leftover strip LEDs lying around. They're just the RGB strip LEDs you can pick up at Five Below. They come with an RGB controller attached to a short USB cable. However, I needed to just cut off a short section of the strip for my project (a single section), and I only have a positive and negative wire, no RGB cables, because I just want white. I only have basic electrical knowledge so I don't know if I'm just going about this the wrong way, but I tried testing it by connecting a wire to the 5V pads on both sides of the section of LEDs and connected them to a female DC adaptor, then connected a USB cable to the adaptor and plugged it into a computer, but nothing happened.

Is there a different way I'm supposed to wire it, or can I not just use the 5V pad and ignore the RGB pads? Or do I connect the negative terminal to a different pad than the 5V pad? Thanks for any help, I know this is probably horribly obvious but most tutorials I find are just for homeowners installing them on their TVs and similar applications and they don't go into specific cases like this.

[image: Positive Terminal]

[image: Negative Terminal]

Comment: looks like you are shorting out your power supply ... you connected the red and green wires to the opposite ends of the same wire

Comment: @jsotola You're gonna have to rephrase that because it didn't make any sense.

Comment: top picture shows a connection to the `+` ... bottom picture shows a connection to the `+` ... the two `+` are connected together through the LED strip ... you are shorting out the two wires going to the power cable

Comment: @jsotola Yes? Because the + pad on the green side would be where the electricity flows out, which I connect to the negative side. How is that a short?

Comment: i said red and green before, but i think that the wire colors are green and orange  ... you are connecting the green wire directly to the orange wire ... that is a short circuit

Comment: are you by chance using the same aligator lead to clamp the two ends?

Comment: @jsotola No, they're separate clips. They're not connected by a wire.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau You have it shorted by one side of the segment's + to the other side's +, to your power supply's + and -. Because of how the led strip is constructed, it is like you just connected a wire directly between your power supply's + and -. Disconnect that immediately.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau It means the electricity is supposed to flow from the +, through the LEDs, and onto the -. Each colour has a separate - which is how the colour can be controlled. In your circuit the electricity flows from one end of the +, down to the other end of the +, so it doesn't actually go through any LEDs.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Welcome to EE.SE. You may wonder, why your question was closed as off-topic. To answer your question AND to enable you to understand the answer one needs a lot of comments (as you saw) and call-backs. It's like asking on a literature forum for the correct spelling of "ask". It can be explained, as you noticed, but it is not the purpose of this Q&A-site. Questions should show minimum knowledge of electricity and some prior research like you having read and understood the datasheet of the LED stripe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get white you'll need all of the colors combined, plug 5 volts to the designated port and then wire all the rest of the wires to ground together. Hope This Helps!

Comment: So split the two wires into four on each side and have them lead back to a single connection on the terminal? Should have thought of that...

Comment: Not sure if I read that right, but you should only need 4 connections on one side, not both.

Comment: Only 4 wires. 1 x +5V red wire to (+),3 x 0V green wires to (R), (G) & (B).

Comment: @TheAdmin I'm not understanding. Could you update your answer with a drawing?

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau The port with a '+' on it... plug the 5 volt onto that. The rest of the ports on the same side should all be plugged directly to ground. Not sure if I explained that any better?

Comment: @TheAdmin Yes, that makes sense. I guess I just wasn't understanding because I'm confused why the ground comes from the same side and not the opposite side of the strip.

Comment: Yeah I completely understand man, I'm pretty new to electronics and its overwhelming trying to wrap your head around all of it haha! Goodluck with your lights!

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Forgot to @ you above... woops!

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau Because the led strip is setup as parallel sections, specifically 3 parallel sections per parallel segment. The connections +, R, G, B, at each end of the strip are connected to each other in order to allow the parallel connection to work, aka passthrough. See http://lednique.com/technology-basics/flexible-led-strip-light/ but just imagine 3 sets of leds per section, for RGB strips.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you! That page actually helped a lot.